# How to aggregate sum on multi columns on Dataframe using reduce function and not groupby?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to aggregate sum on multi columns on Dataframe using reduce function and not groupby? Since, groupby sum is taking alot of time now i am thinking of using reduce function. Any lead will be helpful.

```
Input:

| A | B | C | D |
| x | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| x | 2 | 3 | 4 |

CODE:

    dataFrame.groupBy("A").sum()

Output:

| A | B | C | D |
| x | 3 | 5 | 7 |
```

Comment: You will have to convert the `DataFrame` to `RDD` to perform `reduceByKey` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the `DataFrame` to `RDD` to perform `reduceByKey` operation.

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd
```

Once you create your RDD you can use the reduceByKey to add values of multiple columns

```
val input =  sc.parallelize(List(("X",1,2,3),("X",2,3,4)))
input.map{ case (a, b, c, d) => ((a), (b,c,d)) }.reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 + y._3))


spark.createDataFrame(final_rdd).toDF("M","N").select($"M", $"N._1".as("X"), $"N._2".as("Y"),$"N._3".as("Z")).show(10)

+---+---+---+---+
|  M|  X|  Y|  Z|
+---+---+---+---+
|  X|  3|  5|  7|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I was looking more of a generic rather than 3 columns only. I need to sum around 300 columns at once.